# Element is not clickable at point using chrome driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to download payslip as PDF from greytip web portal using chrome driver.i am trying to click on link salary by using "driver.findElement(By.linkText("Salary")).click();".But i am unable to click the link and failed with following exception.

### Error

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (198, 139). Other element would receive the click: ... (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 37 milliseconds

And also when ever i ran the script chrome open one extra tab for bit torrent.so here when i ran the program one tab is opened for "https://psdpl.greytip.in" and another tab is opened for bittorrent.How can i handle not to open another bittorrent tab when i ran the program.

Here i am attaching the code and screen shots.enter image des[image: bittorrent tab<code>enter code here</code>]cription here
[image: salary link]

Code

```
package com.webdriver.tests;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class PaySlipPDF {
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\soleti\\D-Drive\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
baseUrl = "https://psdpl.greytip.in/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testPayslip() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/login.do");
            driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("101786");
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='home-page']/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
    WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='home-page']/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a"));
    System.out.println(elementToClick);
    // Scroll the browser to the element's Y position
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+elementToClick.getLocation().y+")");
    // Click the element
    elementToClick.click();
    //driver.findElement(By.linkText("Salary")).click();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("View Payslips")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("payroll"))).selectByVisibleText("Mar 2012");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.className("btn btn-gts-print")).click();



}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    //driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
}

private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

It is the BitTorrent toolbar that is causing the issue. It is launched into Chrome by an extension. Either uninstall it completely, or force Selenium to tell Chrome to disable all extensions. This can be done using the ChromeOptions class:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html

Use the addArgument method and give it this arguement, which tells Chrome to disable all user extensions:

```
--disable-extensions
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the browser settings and see if the default homepage has been changed by the bit torrent toolbar that is installed. If not needed, try to uninstall the bitTorrent toolbar from the browser and rerun your selenium program. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is specificaly related to chrome installed on your system..Uninstall the google chrome and re-install it..That will fix your problem..:)